Using spaces in the names of routes in Symfony
Is the following route name valid in Symfony?
#[Route('/{profileId}/bundles/{bundleId}', name: 'data export bundle details')]

In all the examples that I have seen, in the name the words are separated by underscores (it would be data_export_bundle_details for this example).
Looking at the documentation it does not say anything about the allowed characters, it just says that route names need to be unique, so I am guessing that the above name is fine, but can someone confirm?

Using snake case for your name is a symfony recommended practice, so I would keep data_export_bundle_details  (And if you asked wheter it was possible, yes it is. You can easily test by trying it).

The only purpose is to identify the route somewhere else and it's an internal identifier that doesn't need to be exported or serialised, so I presume it's used for simple matching and you might be able to use even emojis (just speculating, I've never tried). The benefit of underscores is that it strongly implies it isn't a mere display label for humans, and editing it can have consequences.

Yes, that would be a valid route.
And it's trivially verified by creating such a route, and verifying it works.
#[Route('/test', name: 'this is test')]
class TestingController extends AbstractController
{
    public function __invoke(): Response
    {
        return new Response('this is a test');
    }
}

$ bin/console debug:router
 ---------------- -------- -------- ------ --------------------------
  Name             Method   Scheme   Host   Path
 ---------------- -------- -------- ------ --------------------------
  _preview_error   ANY      ANY      ANY    /_error/{code}.{_format}
  this is test     ANY      ANY      ANY    /test
 ---------------- -------- -------- ------ --------------------------

http 127.0.0.1:8989/test
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 29 Apr 2024 14:45:49 GMT
Host: 127.0.0.1:8989
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.3.6
X-Robots-Tag: noindex

this is a test

A route name is an arbitrary, application-unique, string. That's it. It's probably better, generally, to avoid naming the routes explicitly and use system generated route names using fully-qualified class names, so you can take advantage of auto-complete.
But it's up to you to do things differently.

I think that to properly verify the name works you need to actually use it, for example, creating a link.
